# How can I replace a CLICK in a <select> dropdown list with a CTRL+CLICK in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, select, mouseevent, ctrl, onmousedown

A client wants a multi-select dropdown list that replaces the normal mouse click behavior with a CTRL+CLICK, as though the CTRL key is pressed while clicking the mouse. The client was warned that this changes expected behavior and wants it anyway. Initially I want to replace the default click behavior with the CTRL+CLICK behavior. I want to use the **select** element and not something else as some posts suggest.

My idea was to stop the click and replace it with a simulated CTRL+CLICK. I added the **onmousedown** attribute to the **select** statement. The JS disables the default click behavior and then I've tried to create and dispatch the same mouse click event with **ctrlKey** set to true...but nothing happens. Nothing is selected or deselected like the default CTRL+CLICK behavior should.

I'm new to JavaScript event handling, so I'm sure I'm missing something. Can someone help?

```
<select id="selectbox" multiple onmousedown="SelectDeselect(event)">
  <option id="option1">A</option>
  <option id="option2">B</option>
  <option id="option3">C</option>
</select>

<script>
function SelectDeselect(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    optn = event.target;
    var ctrlClickEvent  = new MouseEvent("click", {
        ctrlKey: true,
    })
    document.getElementById(optn.id).dispatchEvent(ctrlClickEvent);
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is really nothing you can do with a select to change the behavior. Better off not using a select and using something else.

Comment: CTRL+CLICK is already the default for selecting more than one option within a `<select>` element that has the `multiple` attribute. On Mac, it's the same with COMMAND+CLICK. Are you trying to replace the default behavior of a single mouse click selecting a single option? I'm unclear on how your desired outcome is different from the default behavior.

Comment: The normal click behavior is to deselect everything and then select the item you clicked. I need the click to act like a CTRL+CLICK, which leaves everything as is except for (1) changing the select status on the item clicked and (2) changing the "anchor" for using the SHIFT key in conjunction with the mouse if the select status is changed to selected.

Comment: I should add that (1) is easy to do, just change the "selected" status on the option. I could not find a way to do (2).